# starting service failed docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dcm4che

I follow this install [guide](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Run-minimum-set-of-archive-services-on-a-single-host) run dcm4chee in docker container, when I start the service up by `sudo docker-compose -p dcm4chee start` it gives me error

```
Starting ldap ... done
Starting db   ... done
Starting arc  ... failed
```

this is my [docker-compose.yml](https://justpaste.it/399wc).

docker-compose.env:

```
STORAGE_DIR=/storage/fs1
POSTGRES_DB=pacsdb
POSTGRES_USER=pacs
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pacs
```

Why ldap and db start fine but arc failed.

Edit:

- /var/local/dcm4chee-arc/wildfly:/opt/wildfly/standalone
- /var/local/dcm4chee-arc/storage:/storage

these files are in docker-compose.yml in volumes attribute, but I didn't find `wildfly` folder/file in system.

Answer (score 0):

It worked, the problem is that for some reason this up command (docker-compose -p dcm4chee up -d) failed to create the wildfly and storage folders,
so when I then run start command, the docker failed to start the service as the required folders wasn't created, the solution was simply run up command again,
this time it creates the folders correctly.